# Как правильно дать ссылку на переменную?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно дать ссылку на переменную temp?

Работает:

```
$('.selectCategory option:contains("Хлеб")').prop('selected',true);
```

Не работает(

```
 var temp = ("Хлеб");
 $('.selectCategory option:contains(temp)').prop('selected',true);
```

Comment: Для чего вокруг строки `"Хлеб"` круглые скобки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То что находится внутри `''` просто строка. Вам нужно явно записать в неё значение из переменной.

Можно сделать так:

```
var temp = "Хлеб";
$('.selectCategory option:contains("'+temp+'")').prop('selected',true);
```

либо используя es6

```
const temp = "Хлеб";
$(`.selectCategory option:contains("${temp}")`).prop('selected',true);
```

Comment: Так пробовал "'temp'", так "'+temp+'" не пробовал. Сенкс. Странный синтаксис

Comment: @BogdanShulga, почему странный? Обычная конкатенация.

Comment: Если бы js подставлял значения переменной в середину строки, котораяя по какойто причине, сожержит в себе набор символов последовательность которых совпадает с назвванием одной из переменных, определённых гдето ранее, на нём невозможно былобы писать. Т.к. никогда не знаешь что там *внезапно* появится.

Comment: А теперь заменяем "Хлеб" на ")_(" и наблюдаем последствия :)

Answer (score 3):

Не надо писать сложные селекторы через конкатенацию строк только для того чтобы потом jquery разбирала их обратно.

Вот так это делается правильно:

```
$('.selectCategory option')
  .filter(function() { return this.text.indexOf(temp) !== -1; })
  .prop('selected', true);
```

Или даже вот так:

```
$('.selectCategory option').each(function() {
  if (this.text.indexOf(temp) !== -1)
    this.selected = true;
});
```